# recordset cannot be indexed because has no default property

Tags: vb.net, recordset

So im quite new to VBA so I'm not pretty sure why i am getting the error "Recordset cannot be indexed because has no default property". Thing is it was working couple hours ago in another computer, so any ideas?

Public Class Form1
    Public Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Public RS As New ADODB.Recordset

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SQL
    RS = New ADODB.Recordset
    RS.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset
    RS.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic

    SQL = "SELECT P.descripcion, P.precio FROM Producto P, CATEGORIAS C WHERE C.idcat= P.idcategoria and Idcat=" & TextBox1.Text
    RS.Open(SQL, Conn, , , ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText)
    i = 0
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    If RS.EOF() Then
        MsgBox("NO hay productos registrados para esa Categoría")
    Else
        Do While Not RS.EOF()

            ListView1.Items.Add(RS(0).Value)
            ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(RS(1).Value)
            i = i + 1
            RS.MoveNext()
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Nathan_Sav says set and let are no longer supported

Comment: this is not vba

Comment: @Nathan_Sav even though I'm using visual studio 2017 it doesn't mean its running visual basic?